# cluster images based on similarity

Tags: opencv, image-processing

i am new to opencv in visual studio 2013

i am having images extracted from video(fps=27) now i want to group similar frames into one cluster.

i tried with feature matching with flann

it gave many matches for similar images it gave 20-50 matches and for different images it gave 20-150 matches.even for different images it shows many matches but the images are quietly different, in this case we cannot differentiate images based on their similarity.

can someone help me to cluster images based on similarity.

similarity images which are matched should move to one folder that is one cluster in one folder.

Comment: depends on your definition of "similarity"

Comment: This is non-trivial. What is "different", what is "similar"? You'll need to explain that (or figure it out first).

Comment: You can use SSIM